# how to create pdf in eclipse 3.3 using JSP?

Tags: jsp

```js
<% 
@ page import = "java.io. *, java.awt.Color, com.lowagie.text .*, com.lowagie.text.pdf .*"
%>
<%
response.setContentType ( "application / pdf");
Document document = new Document ();
ByteArra`enter code here`yOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance (document, buffer);
document.open ();
document.add (new Paragraph ( "Hello World"));
document.close ();
DataOutput output = new DataOutputStream (response.getOutputStream ());
byte [] bytes = buffer.toByteArray ();
response.setContentLength (bytes.length);
for(int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++)
{
output.writeByte (bytes [i]);
}
%>
```

it is not working and giving errors as Enumidentifier required to complete EnumHeaderName.
is this code correct??
what should I do now?

Comment: @jeny import java.awt.Color in JSP file?

Comment: Ya I have import that n if this code is not correct than which code should I use??